# AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'screen' in spyder?

Tags: python, spyder, turtle-graphics

What's wrong with this code? I tried to run [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMeyG.png) but in the output' `AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'screen'` is shown:

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
    window = turtle.screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")

    brad = turtle.turtle()
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)

    window.exitonclick()

draw_square()
turtle.done()
turtle.bye()
```

Comment: Case matters. `screen` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code.  First, this:

```
window = turtle.screen()
```

should be this:

```
window = turtle.Screen()
```

Ditto here:

```
brad = turtle.turtle()
```

which should be:

```
brad = turtle.Turtle()
```

Finally, you have a redundancy here:

```
    window.exitonclick()

...
turtle.done()
```

As both `exitonclick()` and `done()` serve the same purpose but in different ways.  Style-wise, I would setup your screen and turtle outside of `draw_square()` and just have that function do what it says it does, draw a square -- below is how I would go about writing this program:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def draw_square(turtle):

    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(90)

window = Screen()
window.bgcolor("red")

brad = Turtle()

draw_square(brad)

window.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a file named    "turtle.py" you should rename it or move it away from working directory
Python interpreter tries to import the file named    "turtle.py" from working directory before importing it from python installation files
If the file itself that generate this error is named    "turtle.py" you must rename it!

Comment: Hello @Ahmad. From the question, I see no reference to a file named `turtle.py`. Could you check again that your answer is not off-topic ?

Comment: Hello, @bertrand-gazanion, This is my guess about the origin of the problem, as I had the same problem and this was the solution for my case♥

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your file name not turtle or Turtle